# TypeError: passport.authenticate is not a function

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

Every time it's throwing the same error. I'm not using createStragety inside passport file. [image]
Here's my Project Repo: https://github.com/naima-shk/Twitter-Clone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw Project Repo in github. you require passport-jwt into a passport variable and use it for passport.authenticate() method. you should  require passport module against passport-jwt in this section. because authenticate mehtod that you use belongs to passport library. I tested your code with this approach and it's worked successfully

Comment: Thanks for the answer but can you please show me the changes you made in my code that worked successfully?